# More detailed report for iTunes "Capacity" bar for iPhone / iPod

Tags: iphone, storage

When I plug my iPhone into iTunes, I see a horizontal "bar" labeled capacity. That bar shows me the space used for "audio", "video","photos", "Apps", "Other" and "Free".

Is there a tool (on Mac/win or iPhone) that can give me more details as to what data (files, folders) is stored in those categories.

I'm especially worried about pruning the steadily growing "other" category almost 4GByte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a support forum thread I found with some suggestions:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=6502415

It sounds like you might try clearing caches, old SMS messages, and stuff like that.

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll be checking it out... my primary motivation here is curiosity, I'd like to know what is eating my space, then step two is pruning it down...

Comment: In mid September my iPhone had 5GByte in the 'other' category. Doing a full restore of the phone in iTunes freed all but ca 200MBytes ..

Comment: three years later ... I just did another full restore, this time freeing roughly 8GB, that where "stuck" somehow .. what is it about my iPhone usage that makes this necessary every 6 month?

Comment: Is it still the same phone you're using? I've never experienced this problem, but I've also been trading out for new devices every 2 years or so. In any case, the Usage settings can show you some interesting info — I'm not sure if app documents/data are included in Apps or Other, according to iTunes.

Comment: No, it's a 'new' (not that new, any more) iPhone4. I did do a restore of the old phone to the 4, however, so whatever is wrong might be carried over. If my 4 lives until summer (home button intermittently stuck) .. I'll be going to a 5s or 6, clean slate .. will see what happens then...

Answer (score 1):

When I copy files to my jailbroken iphone through SSH (files the OS doesnt recognize i suppose), they count as 'other' space.  So when I downloaded a few gigs of maps for XGPS, it was 3GB of 'Other'

Maybe that helps

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [iPhone/iPod space usage information on the device](https://superuser.com/questions/21800/iphone-ipod-space-usage-information-on-the-device/30922#30922).

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting my safari files and pictures and texts, but then I found this link on google that shows lots of different ways to fix it. Cause my other space was 4GB!

http://appducate.com/2013/01/reclaim-other-storage-space-on-ipad-iphone-and-ipod/