# iPhone/iPod space usage information on the device

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, storage, disk-space

iTunes gives an information (capacity bar) of the device (iPod Touch) when connected, with respect to the amount of space used by each category like Audio, Video, Photos, Apps etc. Is there any possibility to get the same information on the device itslef. This could be either through any functionality in the device or through a app.

Edit: I am looking for Disk usage (specifically for applications), and not the item count that is shown under Settings->General->About

Comment: similar to http://superuser.com/questions/4611/more-detailed-report-for-itunes-capacity-bar-for-iphone-ipod/35018#35018

Comment: @lexu, not exactly, you question is for identifying additional information in the Data category.In short you wanted more information than what is being provided (anywhere). I wanted the same information on the Device itself.

Answer (score 4):

Is this something you want?

[image: pie]

If you have jailbroken your iPod Touch, you can use Cydia to check the disk usage.

Cydia->Manage->Storage, then you'll see a nice pie chart.

Comment: I think it comes close to what i need, mine is not a Jail broken Device, and i am not sure whether i should be taking the plunge. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Well, you can't count on official apps to look for disk usage on the device.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not as expressive as the one in iTunes you can do the following to get an idea:
This will tell you the number of songs, videos, photos, applications and disk space available.

1. Open Settings
2. Choose General
3. Choose About.

Comment: Saw that initially, but wasnt enough for me, my real reason for posting this question is to be able to the disk space that applications group uses